# Error with SQL code

Tags: mysql

Trying to execute this code with COALESCE to group data together. When executing I see this error

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Invalid column name 'OrderID'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'CustomerID'.

```
SELECT CustomerID,
FirstName,
LastName,
COALESCE(OrderIDCnt,0),
COALESCE(SKUCnt,0),
COALESCE(OrderTotal,0)
FROM Customer as c
left join (SELECT o.CustomerID,
       SUM(OrderTotal) AS OrderTotal,
       COUNT(OrderedProductSKU) AS SKUCnt,
       COUNT(OrderID) AS OrderIDCnt
       FROM Orders as o
       inner join Orders_ShoppingCart as osc
       on osc.OrderNumber=o.OrderNumber
       and osc.CustomerID=o.CustomerID
       GROUP BY o.CustomerID
      )ord
ON ord.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
```

Comment: Please tag the question according to the SQL you are using (MySql, Sql-Server, Oracle, etc.)

Comment: SELECT c.CustomerID,
c.FirstName,
c.LastName,
COALESCE(c.OrderIDCnt,0),
COALESCE(c.SKUCnt,0),
COALESCE(c.OrderTotal,0)
FROM Customer as c
left join (SELECT o.CustomerID,
       SUM(o.OrderTotal) AS OrderTotal,
       COUNT(o.OrderedProductSKU) AS SKUCnt,
       COUNT(o.OrderID) AS OrderIDCnt
       FROM Orders as o
       inner join Orders_ShoppingCart as osc
       on osc.OrderNumber=o.OrderNumber
       and osc.CustomerID=o.CustomerID
       GROUP BY o.CustomerID
      )ord
ON ord.CustomerID = c.CustomerID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that SQL parser cannot uniquely resolve the unqialified name `CustomerID`. There are two candidates there:

- The `CustomerID` field of the `Customer` table, and
- The `CustomerID` field of the `ord` sub-query.

Although the two must match, because your join condition requires that `ord.CustomerID = c.CustomerID`, the query parser cannot arbitrarily pick one for you. Therefore, you need to either disambiguate this manually by specifying `c` or `ord` in front of `CustomerID`, or pick a different name for `CustomerID` in the subquery.

The first approach:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, -- Add c. in front of CustomerID
FirstName,
LastName,
COALESCE(OrderIDCnt,0),
COALESCE(SKUCnt,0),
COALESCE(OrderTotal,0)
FROM Customer as c
left join (SELECT o.CustomerID,
       SUM(OrderTotal) AS OrderTotal,
       COUNT(OrderedProductSKU) AS SKUCnt,
       COUNT(o.OrderID) AS OrderIDCnt -- Disambiguated OrderID
       FROM Orders as o
       inner join Orders_ShoppingCart as osc
       on osc.OrderNumber=o.OrderNumber
       and osc.CustomerID=o.CustomerID
       GROUP BY o.CustomerID
      )ord
ON ord.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
```

The second approach:

```
SELECT CustomerID,
FirstName,
LastName,
COALESCE(OrderIDCnt,0),
COALESCE(SKUCnt,0),
COALESCE(OrderTotal,0)
FROM Customer as c
left join (SELECT o.CustomerID as OrderCustomerID, -- add an alias
       SUM(OrderTotal) AS OrderTotal,
       COUNT(OrderedProductSKU) AS SKUCnt,
       COUNT(o.OrderID) AS OrderIDCnt -- Disambiguated OrderID
       FROM Orders as o
       inner join Orders_ShoppingCart as osc
       on osc.OrderNumber=o.OrderNumber
       and osc.CustomerID=o.CustomerID
       GROUP BY o.CustomerID
      )ord
ON ord.OrderCustomerID = c.CustomerID -- Rename the field
```

**Edit :** Disambiguated `OrderID`.

Comment: Thanks.Renaming that field resolves one issue. The other one still remains Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Invalid column name 'OrderID'.

Comment: @DeanFraser-Phillips I see - there's also `OrderID` on the `Orders_ShoppingCart` table, right? I added a disambiguation for that, too - please see the edit.

Answer (score 3):

try to use c.CustomerId or ord.CustomerId

Answer (score 0):

You have field named customerId in tables Orders and Customer and you don't specify which you want to include in select clause.

In this case you always should type the field in format  alias.field